# Hibernate JPA Repeated column in mapping for entity error for bi-directional mapping

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities, sale and sale_details. One sale will have many sale_details, but each sale_detail belongs to only one sale, my current code gives me a Repeated column in mapping for entity error.

Sale:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Sales")
public class Sale implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "sale_id", nullable = false)
    private int sale_id;

    @Column(name = "promotionid_fk")
    private int promotionid_fk;

    @Column(name = "grand_total", nullable = false)
    private double grand_total;

    @Column(name = "salespersonid_fk", nullable = false)
    private int salespersonid_fk;

    @Column(name = "customerid_fk", nullable = false)
    private int customerid_fk;

    @Column(name = "storeid_fk", nullable = false)
    private int storeid_fk;

    @Column(name = "expected_date", nullable = false)
    private Date expected_date;

    @Column(name = "pickup_date")
    private Date pickup_date;

    @Column(name = "initial_deposit_date", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime initial_deposit_date;

    @Column(name = "initial_deposit_type", nullable = false)
    private String initial_deposit_type;

    @Column(name = "initial_deposit_amount", nullable = false)
    private double initial_deposit_amount;

    @Column(name = "final_payment_date")
    private LocalDateTime final_payment_date;

    @Column(name = "final_payment_type")
    private String final_payment_type;

    @Column(name = "final_payment_amount")
    private double final_payment_amount;

    //maps one sale to many sale details relationship
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sale", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<SaleDetails> sale_detail_list; //stores list of sale_detail entries where FK saleid_fk field is the ID of this sale


    //default constructor, never used
    public Sale() {
    }

    //creates new sale
    public Sale(int promotionid_fk, double grand_total, int salespersonid_fk, int customerid_fk, int storeid_fk, Date expected_date, LocalDateTime initial_payment_date, String initial_payment_type, double initial_payment_amount) {
        this.promotionid_fk = promotionid_fk;
        this.grand_total = grand_total;
        this.salespersonid_fk = salespersonid_fk;
        this.customerid_fk = customerid_fk;
        this.storeid_fk = storeid_fk;
        this.expected_date = expected_date;
        this.initial_deposit_date = initial_payment_date;
        this.initial_deposit_type = initial_payment_type;
        this.initial_deposit_amount = initial_payment_amount;
    }
```

Sale_details:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sale_Details")
public class SaleDetails implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "sale_detail_id")
    private int saleDetailId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "saleid_fk")
    private Sale sale;

    @Column(name = "saleid_fk")
    private int saleid_fk;

    @Column(name = "productid_fk")
    private int productid_fk;

    @Column(name = "quantity_sold")
    private int quantity_sold;

    public SaleDetails(){
    }

    public SaleDetails(int saleid_fk, int productid_fk, int quantity_sold){
        this.saleid_fk = saleid_fk;
        this.productid_fk = productid_fk;
        this.quantity_sold = quantity_sold;
    }
```

Table structures:
[image]

Im trying to make the relationship bi-directional, what am I doing wrong here? From my understanding the owning side of the relationship is the many-to-one on the sale_details entity, and the mappedby in the sale entity is just referencing that there already is a mapping on the inverse side?

Full error stack trace:

```
Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.owl.server.entities.Sale_Details column: saleid_fk (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to follow [java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html). According to this roles:

> *Classes*: Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.
>
> *Variables*: Except for variables, all instance, class, and class constants are in mixed case with a lowercase first letter. Internal words start with capital letters.

So, I would suggest you to correct your mapping in the following way:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="Sales")
public class Sale implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "sale_id", nullable = false)
    private int saleId;

    @Column(name = "promotionid_fk")
    private int promotionId;

    // ...

    //maps one sale to many sale details relationship
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sale", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<SaleDetails> saleDetails;


    // default constructor, should be present
    // It is used by hibernate for entity instantiation
    public Sale() {
       saleDetails = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    // getters, setters

    // The addSaleDetail() and removeSaleDetail() are utility methods that
    // synchronize both ends whenever a child element is added or removed.
    public void addSaleDetail(SaleDetails saleDetail)
    {
        saleDetails.add(saleDetail);
        saleDetail.setSale(this);
    }

    public void removeSaleDetail(SaleDetails saleDetail)
    {
        saleDetails.remove(saleDetail);
        saleDetail.setSale(null);
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Sale_Details")
public class SaleDetails implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "sale_detail_id")
    private int saleDetailId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "saleid_fk")
    private Sale sale;

    // This should be removed
    // @Column(name = "saleid_fk")
    // private int saleid_fk;

    @Column(name = "productid_fk")
    private int productId;

    // ...

    public SaleDetails(){
    }

    // getters, setters
}
```

1. The value in the `mappedBy` referred to the field name of another side of the association.
2. You can omit to use the `referencedColumnName` if the foreign key referred to the primary key field of target entity.

And an example of creation and saving a new Sale:

```java
Sale sale = new Sale();
sale.setPromotionId(1);

// ...
SaleDetails saleDetail1 = new SaleDetails();
saleDetail1.setProductId(2);
// set other fields except sale
sale.addSaleDetail(saleDetail1);

SaleDetails saleDetail2 = new SaleDetails();
saleDetail2.setProductId(3);
// set other fields except sale
sale.addSaleDetail(saleDetail2);

entityManager.persist(sale);
```

Comment: okay, so i did the changes, but the same error still remains. I dont think this is a syntax error.

Comment: It looks like you did not provide full mapping because I cannot see from the provided mapping where the column `saleid_fk` duplicated.

Comment: uhm, so do you want to see all of the code? because its longer than this, i just cut it down to make the question easier to read.

Comment: i put up the full mapping

Comment: Well, as it suggested in the exception error message you can add `@Column(name = "saleid_fk", insertable = false, updatable = false)` or `@JoinColumn(name = "saleid_fk", insertable = false, updatable = false)` , but I would not suggest to do it. I would suggest just remove `@Column(name = "saleid_fk")` at all and set all related to each other entities via setters.  And please note when you use bidirectional relationship both side of the association should be in-sync.

Comment: I removed @Column(name = "saleid_fk"), and I already have getters and setters for all column variables, the error still perists. How was removing @Column(name = "saleid_fk") supposed to solved the error? I dont get how thats supposed to fix anything.

Comment: Please show how do you persist your entities.

Comment: I dont have any database operations set up, i cant even get the program to deploy successfully because of this error.

Comment: It works now!, thank you so much. My problem was that I set saleid_fk twice which you fixed. thank youuu